# 'select' preparedStatement wih Timestamp returns always empty RecordSet

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, prepared-statement, recordset

I try to retrieve records from ORACLE database table using JDBC thin driver.
The prepared statement I'm using:
(1)

```
SELECT (t1.LOGGED_TIME - ?) AS TDIFF, t1.ID, t1.STATUS, t1.LOGGED_TIME, t1.SERVER_TIME 
        FROM table_1 t1 
        WHERE (
          ((t1.LOGGED_TIME - ?) <= INTERVAL '10' DAY) 
          AND ((t1.LOGGED_TIME - ?) >= INTERVAL '-10' DAY)) 
        ORDER BY t1.LOGGED_TIME DESC
```

where t1.LOGGED_TIME represents a timestamp column. Every three parameters are identical timestamps set with

```
java.sql.Timestamp controlTime = Timestamp.valueOf("2014-08-15 03:52:00");

lookupTime.setTimestamp(1, controlTime);
lookupTime.setTimestamp(2, controlTime);
lookupTime.setTimestamp(3, controlTime);
```

Executing the code works fine - no exceptions or warnings are displayed. Nevertheless the resultset returned by

```
rs =  lookupTime.executeQuery();
```

is empty.

Setting the query to 
(2)

```
SELECT (t1.LOGGED_TIME - TO_TIMESTAMP('2014-08-15 03:52', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi')) AS TDIFF, t1.ID, t1.STATUS, t1.LOGGED_TIME, t1.SERVER_TIME 
FROM table_1 t1 
WHERE (
  ((t1.LOGGED_TIME - TO_TIMESTAMP('2014-08-15 03:52', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi')) <= INTERVAL '10' DAY) 
  AND ((t1.LOGGED_TIME - TO_TIMESTAMP('2014-08-15 03:52', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi')) >= INTERVAL '-10' DAY)) 
ORDER BY t1.LOGGED_TIME DESC
```

returns the expected data.
When I query e.g. strings from another column of the same table with a prepared statement the result is ok.

What I'm missing here? Where is the point? Any idea?

To say it clear: the point is not to identify a kind of wrong date/time format conversion in (2). That will always lead to an oracle error message and can be fixed easily.

The question is: why stays the RecordSet returned by the preparedStatement (1) empty (= not a single record) without any error notification? If the Timestamp format is wrong in any way, why there isn't an error or a warning?

Comment: `TO_TIMESTAMP('2014-08-15 03:52', 'dd.mm.yy hh24:mi')`: that doesn't make much sense. The pattern doesn't match the string.

Comment: How can one trust you that the second query return anything, while this query cannot event run due to errors ? ==> the pattern doesnt match the value in `TO_TIMESTAMP('2014-08-15 03:52', 'dd.mm.yy hh24:mi')` ?

Comment: You're right. Copy & paste error. I've corrected it...

Comment: Your query looks for a time difference that is both >= 10 days, and <= 10 days. So it must be exactly equal to 10 days, right? Kind of strange to write such a query like that. But anyway, Timestamp.valueOf() parses the string using the *default* timezone of the JVM, which might be different from the timezone used when executing TO_TIMESTAMP(), which uses the timezone of the database (or set by the driver when connecting).

Comment: @JB Nizet: not exactly. I'm searching for timedifference <= **10** days and timedifference >= **-10** days. So a timeframe of 20 days, with ten days ahead and ten days back of a certain event, should be returned. At least that was my intention :)

Comment: Ah, sorry, missed the minus sign.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your `TO_TIMESTAMP` format:

```sql
TO_TIMESTAMP('2014-08-15 03:52',
               'dd.mm.yy hh24:mi')
```

`Aug. 14, 2015`, not `Aug. 15, 2014`

**Update**

Actually, I get the following error when trying that one:

```
ORA-01843: not a valid month
01843. 00000 -  "not a valid month"
```

**Update2**

A Java `Timestamp` maps to an Oracle `DATE` data type, not a `TIMESTAMP`. Don't know if that makes a difference, but you might try `TO_TIMESTAMP(?)`.

I would however change the query to allow use of a potential index on `LOGGED_TIME`:

```sql
SELECT ID, STATUS, LOGGED_TIME, SERVER_TIME
  FROM table_1
 WHERE LOGGED_TIME BETWEEN ? AND ?
 ORDER BY LOGGED_TIME DESC
```

Then do all the math in Java:

```java
Timestamp controlTime = Timestamp.valueOf("2014-08-15 03:52:00");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(controlTime);
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -10);
lookupTime.setTimestamp(1, new Timestamp(cal.getTimeInMillis()));
cal.setTime(controlTime);
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 10);
lookupTime.setTimestamp(2, new Timestamp(cal.getTimeInMillis()));
try (ResultSet rs = lookupTime.executeQuery()) {
    while (rs.next()) {
        long tdiffInSeconds = (rs.getTimestamp("LOGGED_TIME").getTime() - controlTime.getTime()) / 1000;
        // other code
    }
}
```

Comment: The reason for the empty resultSet was: the schema used by teh program was different to the schema used by SQL Developer. Because I'm not the owner of the database I have to use the names as provided by the DB admin. So the problem is solved.

Nevertheless thanks for your answer. I've impemented as suggested (also the hint for indexing)

Comment: No need to over-complicate things by doing date arithmetic in Java; passing the same variable to the query twice and using `WHERE LOGGED_TIME BETWEEN ? AND ? + 10` or `WHERE LOGGED_TIME BETWEEN ? AND ? + INTERVAL '10' DAY` should be enough.